# Sum of squared/cubed combinations

Tags: summation, combinations

I was wondering if there is a closed formula for sum of cubed combinations. More precisely, I'd like to compute $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left ( \begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right )^3$$

Obviously, without the "$^3$", the sum is $2^n-1$....

Any idea ?

thanks

Comment: Agree.. thanks a lot, I've missed this post

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Comment: Do I have something to do to "close" this question or the "duplicate" is enough ? (newbie on stackexchange)

Comment: @dcoeurjo:  It needs four or five votes to close as a duplicate.  The remaining should be here soon.  Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134747/sum-of-cubes-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: @dcoeurjo: Is this really a duplicate? The other question asks only for an asymptotic estimate, not a closed form.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: that question asks for an asymptotic estimate, whereas this question seeks a closed form (which usually means exact).

Comment: @robjohn Thanks. Why do you think it should be reopened? I did observe that the other question asked only for an asymptotic estimate,  but I voted to close because the *answers* addressed dcoeurjo's request for a closed form.

Comment: @robjohn After considering further, I now agree with you.  There is room on the site for a more extensive discussion of the nonexistence of a closed form for this sum.  I will vote to reopen.

Comment: I originally voted to close this,  but the question is sufficiently different that I have nominated it for reopening.  The other, similar question asks for an approximation formula.  The answers there mention that no closed-form exists, and cite a paper of Farmer and Leth, which does not give the proof.  I think further discussion of this question is warranted, and our site could benefit from a more detailed discussion of the nonexistence of a closed form for this sum.

Comment: @robjohn As my comment above indicates, I agree for essentially the same reasons. (Also see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9574/25554).) I have nominated the question for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are almost the same as the [Franel numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FranelNumber.html) - just replace the lower limit on $k$ with 0 instead of 1 ($n\choose 0$ is always 1, so this is just a simple shift of the resulting sequence). While there is a closed form expression for the Franel numbers, it requires a [generalised hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), so it isn't enormously satisfying:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^3 = {}_3F_2 (-n,-n,-n;1,1;-1)
$$

Comment: Has anyone looked the sequence up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?