# Is there a closed form for the sum of the cubes of the binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

We know that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n\;\; \text{ and }\;\;
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}
$$
hold for all $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$.
Now I tried to find a similar expression for
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^3
$$
but didn't get anywhere at all. What I found were only asymptotic estimates (see [Sum of cubes of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134747/sum-of-cubes-of-binomial-coefficients) or [Asymptotics of $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\binom n k}^a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74651/asymptotics-of-sum-k-0n-binom-n-ka?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Now is there a closed form for this sum or, what would be even better, for $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^\alpha$ with any $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0$?

Comment: Its been proven no closed formula can exist

Comment: on a positive note, if you add $(-1)^k$ to you sum of cubes, there is closed formula called Dixon's theorem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DixonsTheorem.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These numbers are called the [Franel Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FranelNumber.html). It's proven in [(Petkovšek, M., Wilf, H. and Zeilberger, D. (1996). A=B. Wellesley, MA: A K Peters. p. 160)](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.pdf#page=170) that there is no closed form for these numbers, in terms of the sum of a fixed number of hypergeometric terms.

However, as **@Robert_Israel** points out, the expression could possibly be represented by different types of closed form.

Comment: ... if "closed form" is defined as "the sum of a fixed number of hypergeometric terms".  There could be other types of "closed form".

Comment: @Robert Was just thinking that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The [binomial coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html) for a given pair of $n \geq k \geq 0$ integers can be expressed in terms of a [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) as the following.

> $$
> \binom n k = \frac{(-1)^k(-n)_k} {k!}.
> $$

The expression is [valid](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Binomial_Coefficient#Definition_for_Real_Numbers) even if $n$ is an arbitrary real number.

Here we note two things.

> 1. The Pochhammer symbol $(-n)_k$ is zero, if $n \geq 0$ and $k > -n$.
> 2. The factorial $k!$ can be written as $(1)_k$.

Using these observations, we can express your sums in terms of a [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) $_pF_q$ as the following. For the sum of the binomial coefficients, we have

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k(-n)_k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-n)_k{\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}} = {_1F_0}\left({{-n}\atop{-}}\middle|\,-1\right).
$$
For the sum the square of the binomial coefficients, we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {\binom n k}^2 = \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{(-1)^k(-n)_k}{k!}\right)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left((-n)_k\right)^2}{k!} \cdot \frac{1}{k!} = {_2F_1}\left({{-n, -n}\atop{1}}\middle|\,1\right).
$$
And for the sum of the cube of the binomial coefficients $-$ also known as [Franel numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FranelNumber.html) $-$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {\binom n k}^3 = \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{(-1)^k(-n)_k}{k!}\right)^3 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left((-n)_k\right)^3}{(k!)^2} \cdot \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} = {_3F_2}\left({{-n, -n, -n}\atop{1, 1}}\middle|\,-1\right).
$$
In general, for a positive integer $r$, we have the [binomial sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html)

> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n {\binom n k}^r &= \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{(-1)^k(-n)_k}{k!}\right)^r = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left((-n)_k\right)^r}{(k!)^{r-1}} \cdot \frac{(-1)^{rk}}{k!} \\ &= {_rF_{r-1}}\left({{-n, -n, \dots, -n}\atop{1, \dots, 1}}\middle|\,(-1)^r\right).
> \end{align*}
> $$